# React Hook does not set on first API call

Tags: react-native

So I am sure I am messing something up, but I am not super skilled at API.

So I am trying to make an API call to check if the user exists, if user exists then move about business, if not then do other stuff.

So my first call gets the data, and the user DOES exist, the hook is setting to true, however in my log it fails and the next API is ran. However if I do it a 2nd time, it is true...

What am I doing wrong.

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const data = await axios
      .get(`URL`, {
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        if (resp.data.user.name) {
          setCheckUser(true);
          console.log(resp.data.user.name);
        }
        return data;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // Handle Error Here
        console.error(err);
      });
    

    console.log(checkUser);

    if (!checkUser) {
      console.log('No User Found');
      //Do Stuff//
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that setCheckUser(true) is an async operation, so there is no guarantee  that the checkUser variable will turn to true right away.

Maybe you can solve this by using a useEffect block like this

```
//somewhere on the top of your file, below your useState statements
useEffect(()=> {
   if (!checkUser) {
     console.log('No User Found');
     //Do Stuff//
   }
}, [checkUser])

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  const data = await axios
  .get(`URL`, {
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    if (resp.data.user.name) {
      setCheckUser(true);
      console.log(resp.data.user.name);
    }
    return data;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Handle Error Here
    console.error(err);
  });

};
```

Comment: does this work even if the do stuff section includes API calls?

Comment: Yes, the code inside the useEffect will run every time the checkUser value is changed. You can check if the user does not exist inside that block and make an API call

Comment: ok, i just tired it as is, and it still comes up as false.

Comment: never mind... stupid error... it worked. Thank you!

Comment: but the API call is going to be async as well... that wont play nice in the useEffect though?

Comment: It won't matter I think, what you do after the API call completes (like set another local state to a new variable) will run and will not cause any issues. Remember that useEffect will run every time any of the variables inside the dependency array changes, in your case [checkUser]. So the only problem I see is if you constantly try to change the checkUser variable, you may run into an infinite loop.

Comment: ok the only other thing is its running right when the app is launched. Which is causing issues.

Comment: I see, the checkUser is false when the app starts and so the useEffect block is run. What you can do is use another local state like const [isFirstTime, setFirstTime] = useState(true). Then inside the useEffect check this: if (!checkUser && !isFirstTime). Then inside the handleSubmit function, before you make the API call setIsFirstTime(false).